# How to add a company logo to Google Site Search results?

Tags: google-custom-search

I've signed up for the paid account of Google Site Search.

The documentation is very bad.

Does anyone know how I add my company's logo to the results page?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

check out this url, maybe help you.

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/logos?hl=ro

I have used this code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://yoursiteURL.com",
  "logo": "http://yoursiteURL.com/images/logo.png"
}
</script>
```